# Adding a view to a panel

Tags: panels

Running Drupal 7, Views 3 and panels 3

Been searching for an answer for this for a few hours now and I can't seem to find one. I am creating a custom user profile page in panels. I created a view to display certain fields from profile2 if that user is of that role. When I test the view at the bottom of the views page by passing it an id it works fine. here are the settings:

```
Contextual filters:
Node:Nid

Relationships:
Content:Author
(author) User: Profile
```

Now in panels when I add this view I have the heading Content: Nid with a drop down list in the options. I select the information I want to display and save. Then when I go to the profile page, nothing shows up. I don't think it is passing the nodeid to the view, but I am not sure what I haven't done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you create the view as a content pane (panel pane), you are able to select options used in panels on how to receive the context params, (Like from a Panel context of type Node). When adding the content pane in Panels you also get to select which variables should be sent to the view. This is probably what you are missing.

[image: SS 1]
[image]

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention that step. I do already have this and still nothing shows.  When I go into panels and select add content and then click on the view I created it asks what version of the view I want (block, page, etc) but the only choice I have is "master" ... shouldn't there be a choice called "content pane"?

Comment: @Jeremy You're doing it wrong. The content pane will show up in "View panes". If you select it under views, you don't get the integration that content panes provide.

Comment: I knew it boiled down to me being a retard. Thanks, I spent so much time on that and if I had just taken a second to go over the documentation again.... anyways thanks!

Comment: Just FYI, I needed to manually flush the cache before the new pane actually would show up in View Panes or Views.

Answer (score 6):

In Module list: look out for Chaos Tools → then ativate the submodule: Views Content Panes (Allows Views content to be used in Panels).

Practically you'll find this new feature while on the Views UI when add a new Display (you'll notice Content Pane display)

Checkout this tutorial:
http://dev.nodeone.se/node/555

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get it to work:

- goto: admin/structure/panels/settings/panel-page
- click on Allowed View panes content
- Check the box of the view you want to add in panels

  Note: It might be necessary to create a "Content pane" view using the views module of the view you want to add.